# OpenSll MD2 разные данные

Tags: c++, openssl

Использую MD2 хеш-функцию. Не могу понять почему при одинаковых строках результат разный. И как тогда сравнивать их между собой после использование хещ-функции.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <openssl\mdc2.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main();



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");                    // корректное отображение Кириллицы
    char decrypted[128] = " ", message[128] = " ", IfFile[128] = " ", OfFile[128] = " ";
    unsigned char userKey[128] = " "; // буфер промежуточного хранения считываемого из файла текста
    int n;

    MDC2_CTX md2;
    unsigned char mdchar[3][100] = { "привет", "пока", "привет"};
    MDC2_Init(&md2);

    MDC2_Final(*mdchar, &md2);

    cout << mdchar;

    unsigned char md[10][MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH];
       int i;
       MDC2_CTX c;
       static char *text[2] = { "Hello" , "Hello"};



         MDC2_Init(&c);

         MDC2_Update(&c, (const unsigned char*)text[1], strlen(text[1]));
         MDC2_Final(&(md[0][0]), &c);

         MDC2_Update(&c, (const unsigned char*)text[0], strlen(text[0]));
         MDC2_Final(&(md[1][0]), &c);


        // cout << md[1];

            for (i = 0; i < MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
            printf("%02X", md[0][i]);
            printf("\n");

            for (i = 0; i < MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
                printf("%02X", md[1][i]);
                printf("\n");
                int q;
                cin >> q;
}
```

Comment: Тут слишком много кода, выделите только тот, что имеет отношение к вопросу. А так я понимаю, что у вас вот здесь проблема: MDC2_Init(&c);
MDC2_Update(&c, (const unsigned char*)text[1], strlen(text[1]));
MDC2_Final(&(md[0][0]), &c);
MDC2_Update(&c, (const unsigned char*)text[0], strlen(text[0]));
MDC2_Final(&(md[1][0]), &c); ? Если да, то тогда я подозреваю потому что контекст хеширования (`с` в вашем случае) наверно все-таки надо заново проинициализировать после выполнения первого хеширования, он же у вас после первого хеширования не находится в изначальном состоянии.

Comment: спасибо, переделал и всё работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код изменил

```
   MDC2_Init(&c);

             MDC2_Update(&c, (const unsigned char*)text[1], strlen(text[1]));
             MDC2_Final(&(md[0][0]), &c);
```

На `MDC2((const unsigned char*)s, strlen(s), md[nn]);`
Как я понял это все из-за того что  у меня было хеширование состояние теряло, и поэтому хэшировало по другому.

**Вот рабочий код на Visual Studio 2015 с библиотекой OpenSSL. Может кому понадобиться.**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <openssl\camellia.h>



#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>
#include <openssl\mdc2.h>
using namespace std;

int main();



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");                    // корректное отображение Кириллицы

            vector<string> arr;
            vector<string>::iterator i;
            ifstream ifs;
            string str;

            ifs.open("file.txt");
            if (!ifs.is_open()) {
                cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;
                return 1;
            }

            while (!ifs.eof()) {
                getline(ifs, str);

                arr.push_back(str);
            }

            ifs.close();

            int nn = 0;
            int size = arr.size();
            unsigned char md[100][MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH];
            unsigned char qq[MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH];


            for (i = arr.begin(); i != arr.end(); i++)
            {
                //cout << *i << endl;
                const char *s = (*i).c_str();
                MDC2((const unsigned char*)s, strlen(s), md[nn]); //хеш - функция md2
                nn++;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                cout << arr[j] << ": ";
                for (int q = 0; q < MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH; q++)
                    printf("%02X", md[j][q]);

                 printf("\n");
            }

            string nom;

            unsigned char result[MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH];

            cout << "Введите строку для поиска: ";
            cin >> nom;

            const char *nomer = nom.c_str();


            MDC2((const unsigned char*)nomer, strlen(nomer), result); //хеш-функция md2 для искомой строки


            for (int q = 0; q < MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH; q++)
                printf("%02X", result[q]);
            cout << " :";

            for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
            {
                if (memcmp(md[z], result, MDC2_DIGEST_LENGTH) == 0) //сравнивание строк
                {
                    cout << "Подходит: "  << arr[z] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            system("pause"); // Команда задержки экрана

    return 0;

}
```

**И само задание как звучало.**

Преобразование строки с использованием хеш-функции MD2. На входе программы файл со списком строк, с помощью хеш-функции преобразуем все строки. Затем на вход подаем искомую строку, также с помощью хеш-функции преобразовываем ее и ищем в общем списке преобразованных строк.